# Issus to add new objects in firestore using node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to the Firestore and I have added this code to add data in Firestore.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./cred.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();

const obj = {
 fname: "Sachin",
 lanme: "Shah"
};

return db.collection("testApp")
.doc("test")
.set(obj)
.then(() => {
  console.log("Add data to firebase successfully...");
 });
```

By this code, my object is added successfully.

Issue: When I re-run my code, It'll overrider the existing record. I need to add another (new) object.

I didn't understand why it updates my old data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) works when you pass it one argument.  If you want to modify an existing object, use [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) instead. Or, call set() with two parameters, with the second parameter being `{ merge: true }` to leave the unchanged document fields alone.

You might want to review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for adding data to Firestore.

Comment: I have tried the `merge` option. And still, it updates the existing object. I need to add another object.

Comment: Your link helps me to fix my issue. Thanks for the reply. :)